# comparing date in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I want to code a function that take a year as parameter and return the person that born in that year. But my people table format like 1993-01-06 00:00:00 so how can i compare date and return the filtered person in sql?

Comment: What is the data type of this "date" in your table?  If it is anything other than DATE, then you have a serious design failure that should be corrected.  Two people have shown you how to deal with it if it is _not_ a DATE, but that should not be understood as an endorsement of that design.  If it is not a DATE, then you have _zero_ guarantee of the format and how to interpret it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your table has a column with the `DATE` data type then:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  date_column >= TO_DATE( :year || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' )
AND    date_column <  TO_DATE( ( :year + 1 ) || '-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD' );
```

*(Use a range of dates rather than using `EXTRACT` or `TO_CHAR` on your date column as this allows Oracle to use an index on the date column.)*

If your column has a string data type with a 4-digit year:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  string_column LIKE :year || '-%'
```

*(Don't just concatenate `%` as, if you have historical years then, trying to match the year `200` would also match the year `2000`.)*

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of a the column is a string, then you can use:

```
where col like :year || '%'
```

If the data type is a date or timestamp, then you can use:

```
where extract(year from col) = :year
```